# Как программно получить html-разметку из aspx файла и отравить ее на компьютер-клиент?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, aspx

Есть такая форма

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно по нажатию на кнопку «Напечатать» отправить на компьютер-клиент html-файл с этой формой. Как можно получить html-код из aspx-кода программно?

Comment: у вас на скрине и есть html, полученный вероятно из aspx файла.

Comment: @tym32167 это да, но мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы пошла загрузка bill.html на компьютер пользователя и там была не форма, а только таблица

Comment: ну то есть вам надо 1) Сделать страничку с той информацией, что вам требуется 2) Сделать скачивание это странички по примеру, например [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897675/312041), [два](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/may/21/downloading-a-file-with-a-save-as-dialog-in-aspnet)

Comment: @tym32167 а html-код этой страницы мне придется писать руками? Просто он уже написан частично в .aspx а частично в методе Page_Load aspx.cs файла. Программно его оттуда никак не вытащить? Могу добавить код aspx и aspx.cs если нужно

Comment: Вам не надо писать HTML совсем, вам надо написать нужный вам aspx, а после, когда клтент будет грузить старничку, asp.net сервер сам конвертирует aspx в html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить разметку программно, оберните нужное содержимое в элемент типа `<div runat="server" id="divContent">`. Тогда в коде вы сможете получить ее так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//...

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter wr =new StringWriter(sb);

    Page page = new Page();
    HtmlHead head = new HtmlHead();
    head.Title = "Title";
    page.Controls.Add(head);
    HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();
    page.Controls.Add(f);
    f.Controls.Add(this.divContent);
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, wr, true);
    wr.Flush();

    string html = sb.ToString();
}
```

Затем полученную строку можно отправить в Response (собственно, можно сразу писать в Response.OutputStream вместо StringBuilder). Чтобы заставить браузер скачать файл вместо отображения, можно либо выставить Content-Type в `application/octet-stream`, либо добавить `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Если же нужно просто заставить браузер скачать текущую страницу как есть, можно поступить проще:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=form.html");
```

Ну и наконец, странно что вы в кнопке "Напечатать" хотите сделать скачивание файла. Возможно, вместо этого лучше реализовать вызов диалога печати:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script1", "window.print();",true);
```